# Getting element without id

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I want to use jquery datepicker validation to validate date.. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sinceedit").datepicker({
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      onSelect: function(selected) {
        $("#toedit").datepicker("option","minDate", selected)
      }
    });
    $("#toedit").datepicker({ 
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      onSelect: function(selected) {
       $("#sinceedit").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)
     }
   });  
  });
</script>
```

This is the HTML tag :

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <input type="text" class="form-control document-date" name="since" id="sinceedit<?php echo $u->id; ?>" value="<?php echo $user->taken_since ? date("d.m.Y", strtotime($user->taken_since)) : ''; ?>" placeholder="" />
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3">
  <input type="text" class="form-control document-date" name="to" id="toedit<?php echo $u->id; ?>" value="<?php echo $user->taken_to ? date("d.m.Y", strtotime($user->taken_to)) : ''; ?>" placeholder="" />
</div>
```

At this case the hs validation is not working because of the html id `sinceedit<?php echo $u->id; ?>`

But if I change this Id to `sinceedit`, the js is working...

But I also need those `<?php echo $u->id; ?>` part in id, because of other dependencies..

How do I solve this issue? I am totally novice at js.

Comment: The settings are the same so just use the class `$(".document-date").datepicker({ ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know how many such inputs will be on the page?

If they're created dynamically and the number of them could change, then your JS will need to be dynamic as well. One solution is to use inline Javascript with PHP. Define functions you may need to call on those inputs in your external script file, then inline try passing them in as arguments, for example:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  doThingWithInput($('.sinceedit<?php echo $id; ?>'));
});
</script>
```

But in your case, you most likely want to use the jQuery each() function. Write a selector that will select ALL the inputs you want to use, and write a callback function that will be called on each of them individually. [Look here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

```
$('input').each(function() { .... });
```

EDIT: Actually, if all you have is a min and max, you should be able to give a class to each one and select them that way. Or simpler yet, select by name.

```
<input class="form-control document-date from-date" .... />
$('.from-date').doCoolStuff();


$('input[name="since"]').doCoolStuff();
```

Comment: Thanksss.... Using the class name solved that... I have to learn some js basic atleast.. :(